# My Kohler Courage mower runs and starts good most of the time

Tags: starting, small-engine, lawnmower, kohler

This motor starts good most of the time. But in the last couple years. It like stops up against a compression stroke and won't turn over. I have to turn the crank a little and it will start right up. Any ideas on what to do to fix this problem? This mower is 8 years old.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What *exactly* happens when it "won't turn over"? I take it, this engine has an electric starter? Is your question specifically about starting? The way it's written there are inclinations it quits while running? Just trying to make sure I understand your question.

Comment: If I'm understanding your issue correctly, it sounds like the battery may be getting a bit weak.  Start by ensuring all battery and starter connections are clean and tight.  Try jumping the battery when this condition occurs.  If this helps and if you have a smart charger, charge the battery and leave it on for about a week to go through the desulfating process if the charger has it.  Sometimes that can bring a weak battery back for a bit longer.

Comment: How do you know it's against a compression stroke - have you removed the spark plug and verified, or is this just an assumption?   You might be suffering a kind of hydraulic lock because liquid fuel, driven by gravity,  is filling the cylinder while the engine is off and your starter can't turn with that kind of load.  Do you have a fuel cutoff valve and using it?  I had this unable-to-crank problem with a John Deere after owning it for years with no such problem.  I pulled the plug and the cylinder had lots of gas in it after sitting for a few days. Adding fuel cutoff solved the issue.